# Convert aliased Mysql into cakePHP find statement

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Please help me to convert this query into cakePHP find statement --

```
mysql> select auctions.id, auctions.price, products.target_price, (auctions.price / products.target_price) as target_ratio FROM auctions LEFT JOIN products ON auctions.product_id = products.id ORDER BY target_ratio DESC;
```

In particular, I've having difficulty getting this sections to work:

```
 (auctions.price / products.target_price) as target_ratio
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the ratio part you should use [Virtual Fields](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#Virtual-fields-1608).
The join should be done automatically if your models have a belongsTo or hasOne relationship, otherwise you can [join them manually](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#Joining-tables-1047).

Comment: Thank you.  Ok, the join is being done automatically by cake.

Comment: I have added 
var $virtualFields = array('target_ratio' => '(auctions.price / products.target_price)';

Comment: (I don't like the auto submit on enter) -- I added that code into the top section of the model, but the field is still not appearing when I do a Cake Find. Is there a certain way this would be called from the find?  The Cakebook was unclear on this point.  It makes it sound like all I have to do is add that line, and it will just appear in the query results.  This is not working.